# Opening target="_blank" links in Xamarin.Forms WebView

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I have an application written in Xamarin.Forms that mimics a web browser and am trying to open a link that is target="_blank" to open in a new tab. The specific website is: https://app.senecalearning.com/ and then try to login via Google or Microsoft. On both Android and iOS this would originally give an error saying that popups were blocked by the browser. I have managed to fix this in the Android renderer by setting:

Control.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(false);

But iOS is proving a little trickier.

In the iOS project I have added a new CustomWebViewRenderer:

```
public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer, IWKUIDelegate
    {
        public CustomWebViewRenderer()
        {

        }

        public CustomWebViewRenderer(WKWebViewConfiguration config) : base(config)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (NativeView != null)
            {
                WeakUIDelegate = this;
            }
        }

        [Export("webView:createWebViewWithConfiguration:forNavigationAction:windowFeatures:")]
        public WKWebView CreateWebView(WKWebView webView, WKWebViewConfiguration configuration, WKNavigationAction action, WKWindowFeatures features)
        {
            if (action.Request.Url != null)
                webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(action.Request.Url));

            return null;
        }
    }
```

And this seems to work, however only on the second time either the login via Google or Microsoft button is tapped. The first time does not hit CreateWebView and causes the popup blocked message.

Testing this on a simulator targeting iOS 16.4.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: it's similar to this issue:[When using WkWebViewRenderer, links with "target = _blank" do not respond](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8028)

Comment: Have you tried it on a physical device? Found no issue on physical device.